# Where would I find conf folder after installing neo4j- 3.3.0 commuity edition?

Tags: neo4j

I just downloaded neo4j 3.3.0 community edition on my windows System .I could'nt find conf folder in my "C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.3.0" and also in "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb". Please Guide me .

Comment: That's interesting. The [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/configuration/file-locations/) says that it should be in `<neo4j-home>\conf\neo4j.conf` on Windows.

Comment: I am new to neo4j .Please tell me where to find <neo4j-home>?

Comment: It should be `C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.3.0` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Use Neo4j Desktop, there you have "Settings" under "Manage".

Otherwise see file locations: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/